# Flutter full Screen on Condition

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

**Enter and exit full screen on user choice**

If the `fullScreen` value changes I have to enter the FullScreen screen or exit as per the value true or false. But this code I have used was not giving any change to the app UI. Is there a way in Flutter to make dynamic changes to the app layout?

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  fullScreen
      ? SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])
      : SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
  return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    title: 'At Auction',
    theme: ThemeData(
      accentColor: Colors.white,
      primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 191, 166, 1),
      primarySwatch: primary,
    ),
    initialRoute: '/login',
    routes: {
      '/login': (context) => LoginScreen(),
      '/newProduct': (context) => AddProduct()
    },
  );
}
```

I am using `CupertinoSwitch` for changing the value of the `fullScreen` variable

```
CupertinoSwitch(
    value: fullScreen,
    onChanged: (bool val) {
      print(val);
      setState(() {
        fullScreen = val;
      });
    },
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`await SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);` after awaiting next call set state from an asynchronous method, that might work, don't call it from build.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks for the suggestions. This code works fine for me**

```
CupertinoSwitch(
  value: fullScreen,
  onChanged: (bool val) {
    print(val);
    setState(() {
      fullScreen = val;
      fullScreen
          ? SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])
          : SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(
              SystemUiOverlay.values);
    });
  },
)
```